# Not able to click save button in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

I am working on a UI automation project. I have to fill details in a form and click on 'Save' button. Once save button is clicked in manual flow, it turns grey and disabled. And after that a pop-up emerges to confirmation.

But when I run automation script to hit 'Save' button, script hits the button but it doesn't turn grey and still enabled. And I don't see any confirmation pop-up.

I tried lots of solutions for clicking 'Save' button, some of them are listed below but nothing works

```
     cy.contains('Save').click()
     cy.contains('Save').click({force:true})
     cy.contains('Save').focus().type("{enter}")
     cy.get('button span.MuiButton-label').contains('Save').click({force:true})

     cy.get('span.MuiButton-label').contains('Save'). then($btn => {
        cy.wrap($btn).scrollIntoView().click({force:true});
     })
```

[image]

I am also attaching html for 'Save' button

[image]

[image]

I would be really thankful, if you please help me in finding solution for it.

Comment: Can you confirm your .get()/.contains() return the correct element?

Comment: cy.contains('Save').trigger("mouseover").click({force:true})  this helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have shadow DOM in the HTML, turn on `includeShadowDom` either in global config or in the test config.

Target the `button` in the `cy.contains()`. `cy.contains('Save')` will target the label, but that may not be clickable:

```js
it('fills form', {includeShadowDom: true}, () => {

  // fill form fields

  cy.contains('button', 'Save').should('be.enabled').click()

})
```

Comment: thanks for your time and efforts. I tried your all 3 solutions but none is working for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from the image is the button contains some span and other empty elements if you can give the button an id this way you job would be much simpler

`cy.get('#form-btn').click()`

if not then treaverse from the `main-content` to the `form` then to the `button`

`cy.get('#main-content').get('form').get('button').click()`

Comment: thanks for your inputs. The problem is that most of my solutions are hitting the save button but it is expected that after hitting 'Save' button it will be greyed out and disabled which is actually happening when we click 'Save' button in manual testing.

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-cy="save"` to your button and

Do this:

```
cy.get("[data-cy=save").click()
```

Comment: can't tell you the rest because your code is not complete but after clicking you button you can do whatever you want with your popup on new line

Comment: Thanks for your time @sonny49. I tried with cy.get("[data-cy=save]").click() and cy.get('[data-cy=save]').click() but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the button text and click on it.

```js
cy.contains('Save').should('be.visible').click({force: true})
```

Comment: this solution also hits 'Save' button but it is still not greyed out and can be clicked again. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can try adding `{force: true}` with click. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Alapan Das. That's also not giving desired result.

Comment: Please check whether your button is inside an iframe or shadow dom.

Comment: it looks like shadow dom to me. I didn't find iFrame.

Comment: I tried following statment just now                                        
 cy.get('button.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-contained.MuiButton-containedSecondary.MuiButton-containedSizeLarge.MuiButton-sizeLarge')             but it got stuck at shadow().

Comment: Hi @alapandas, this element has flex element in it. I am adding some more information to original question.

Comment: I just tried another solution but it is not working. cy.get('div.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-item.MuiGrid-grid-xs-12.MuiGrid-grid-sm-12.MuiGrid-grid-md-12.MuiGrid-grid-lg-12')
       .eq(2)
       .within(() => {
         cy.contains('span', 'Save').click()
       })

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers were correct.

Additionally, you also want to check the colour change after clicking on the `Save` button. So you should have to check the CSS file and check the colour. I'm assuming here the button has some property `color` and you have to just use that HEX code for the colour. I used Charcoal colour as I don't know which grey shade your app used.

```
cy.contains('Save')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click({ force: true })
  .should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(54, 69, 79)')
```